# Searching for Graphic libraries to draw seismic data in C#

Tags: c#, graphics

I am searching for graphic libraries that can draw seismic data; which is a large number of curves drawn vertically and gives you a shape like this:

[alt text http://img237.imageshack.us/my.php?image=seismicdataxb2.png](http://img237.imageshack.us/my.php?image=seismicdataxb2.png)

and I need it to do be able to:

1) select each curve with mouse and return a value that tells me which curve that I have selected.

2) label the scale with more than one value.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about creating a WPF application? This probably gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, old question I know; but INT sell a series of visualization libraries (including .NET) for this type of thing:

http://www.int.com/

Their C++ libraries are also cross-platform: I used to work for a company that used them in X Windows and MS Windows. This was a big deal in those days (circa. 2000).